# Implement deferred deep linking in electron app

Tags: electron, windows-installer, nsis, deep-linking, electron-builder

In our web page, we have a list of documents and a button to open the document in the electron application. This button actually has the custom protocol href with the document ID passed as parameter.

This electron app can only be used when launched from the browser (using a custom protocol "my-custom-protocol://document-id-here"). Depending on the parameters passed, we decide which document to open in the electron application.

If the user tries to open the app directly (not using link in the browser), we just show a message that this app can only be used when launched from a browser and then just quit the app.

Now, if the user has not installed the application on his machine and tries to open the custom protocol link form the browser then we prompt the user to install the application first and then again try opening the link. This is an example of basic deep linking and is working fine.

For the sake of better UX, we want to change this behavior. So now when the user tries to open the custom link (which also includes the documentID as parameter) and the application is not installed, we will prompt the user to install the application. But once the application is installed, we would like to automatically launch the application with the correct parameters (documentID for whichever document the link was clicked.) so that the correct document will open when the app launches after installation (We want to implement deferred deep linking).

I've seen [this page](https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis#custom-nsis-script) but couldn't find enough information to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this problem is by including the identifier in the in the name of the executable that gets downloaded, like `myAppName_[identifier].exe`. The `[identifier]` part will change based on what document is being opened. Then during app installation we can read the executable file name (this process varies in different OS), extract the identifier and then use it to open the correct document.